# Different latency time when measured through javascript vs developer console

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, latency

I am testing latency of a call through javascript and developer console.

In JS the measurement is done simply by adding start time variables e.g:

```
var start_execution=Math.floor( new Date().getTime() );

// - Call a URL asynchronously
element = doc.createElement("script");
element.src = request_url;
doc.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].parentNode.appendChild(element);

//In response of the call initialize end time and call function to compute latency
 var end_execution=Math.floor( new Date().getTime() );

// function call to generate latency 
calculateLatency();


function calculateLatency(){
  var latency= end_execution-start_execution;
}
```

The method works fine if run in isolation where the latency figure is inline with the browser's developer-console/network panel. But on actual website with lots of asynchronous content, the numbers measured by JS is inflated upto 5X.

One 1000ms latency computed through js shows as 200ms in network panel.

This behavior is very frequent and the difference varies.

I suspect there is some sort of browser queue which handles asynchronous processing and if in case of peak load the request/response gets stuck in queue.

The option I am exploring is Performance  http://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing , but the browser support is limited here.

I am looking for some explanations around the behavior and ability to compute actual latency in javascript (same as shown in net-panel). Also recommendation on how to effectively use JS cutoff time for network calls as in such cases the inflated values might lead to unexpected behavior.

**Why I want to do this:** Set out timeout for non performing network calls but it is not fair to use setTimeOut and reject calls when the actual cause of latency is browser processing overhead.

Comment: It seems to me that the network panel will measure the time the request took, nothing about what happened before and what happened after. So you at least miss the time when your event handler is queued and when it's actually executed.

Comment: Please show us your actual code. What do you do in "*Call a URL asynchronously*"? Through which means do you load it? In what callback do you hook your "end"?

Comment: Added the code which is used to call URL, the response of the call contains call to the function which calculates latency.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right in your suggestion.

Almost everything in JS is driven by events (except some cases like page parsing process).
Any browser has single thread per window for javascript's events and every event handler executes consequently and every event (including propagation/bubbling and defaults) will be processed completely before processing next event.

For more information refer to [this tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth)

As for recommendations on effective usage of events queue, there are some advice:

- Avoid long-running scripts
- Avoid synchronous `XMLHttpRequest`
- Do not allow scripts from different frames being controlling the same global state
- Do not use `alert` dialog boxes for debugging since they may completely change your program logic.

Comment: The event queue should not make up for a 800ms difference though

Comment: Yes that is correct the difference I am seeing is very high, which seems weird considering latest browser and processing.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use http://momentjs.com/ to about anything that is time related. In addition to that I would use duration plugin https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format.

## jQuery

To use it in jQuery manual style

```
var start_execution = moment();
var end_execution   = moment();

var jqxhr = $.get( "google.com", 
  function(data) {
    end_execution = moment();
  })
  .done(function() {
    end_execution = moment();
  })
  .fail(function() {
    end_execution = moment();
  })
  .always(function() {
    var ms = start_execution.diff(end_execution);
    var duration = moment.duration(ms);
    console.log(duration);
  });
```

This is correctly written and will work even if request fails or timeouts.

Just for clarification, It would be wrong to write :

```
var start_execution = moment();
var jqxhr = $.get( "google.com", 
  function(data) {
    //do something with the data;
  });
var end_execution   = moment();
var ms = start_execution.diff(end_execution);
var duration = moment.duration(ms);
console.log(duration);
```

As it measures nothing other then how much time it takes jQuery to create request initialization, most likely end_execution happens before actual request for that asset/url is even sent out.

## Angular

With Angular you write httpInterceptorService, that can log the times when events happened.

```
var HttpCallsApp = angular.module("HttpCallsApp", []);
HttpCallsApp.config(function ($provide, $httpProvider) {
    $provide.factory("MyHttpInterceptor", function ($q) {
        var log = ApplicationNamespace.Util.logger;
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                log.info("Ajax %s request [%s] initialized", config.method, config.url);
                return config || $q.when(config);
            },
            response: function (response) {
                log.info("Ajax %s response [%s] compleated : %s ( %s )",
                    response.config.method, response.config.url, response.status, response.statusText);
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },
            requestError: function (rejection) {
                log.info(rejection);
                // Return the promise rejection.
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            },
            responseError: function (rejection) {
                log.info(rejection);
                // Return the promise rejection.
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    });
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push("MyHttpInterceptor");
});
```

In angular case application namespace contains application scope logger instance timestamps that i set in app config with `logEnhancerProvider.datetimePattern = "HH:mm:ss.SSS";`. From code quality perspective angular case is order of magnitude better, but I prefer not to go in details - it is not that you can not write same thing in jQuery, but it is not your default option.

## Chrome adhoc test (or about any other modern browser)

- ctrl + shift + n (opens new incognito window, ensures assets are not cached client side)
- F12 (opens developer tools)
- network (shows assets requests)
- set to record network log
- enter your url you want to test
- Click XHR filter
- Open the item and "Timing"

You should see something like :

[image]

## Fiddler

If you don't trust your webbrowser or javascript is ran out of browser - in flash, .net, java etc program. You can still get the request timings. In that case you monitor packets sent.

You can see about anything you would want to know:
[image]

As a personal preference I have changed completed time time-stamp format.

---

Instead of using datetime, where milliseconds can vary depending on system factors you could use **console.time()** and **console.timeEnd()** (does not exist in old ie). Even better if you can use [**performance.now**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now), but it has it's own problems. That is why I prefer to use **momentjs**.

If you want to do this accurately and in legacy "browsers" then at least in Google they have used following approach : you add a flash component, that can do this accurately. This would bring other problems, like data pipeline limits if you log a lot, but they are easier problems to solve then create support for legacy IE.

Comment: Usually developers end up using good/accurate enough solution. They do not care about details and usually they should not, as early optimization is root to all evil. Client usually cares about *perceived performance* and you should put your effort in there.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed options  but unfortunately I can not add new libraries to the site. My motive is not just measure but to reject non performing calls based on the time they are taking and blindly doing it using setTimeout is unfair in scenarios where browser overhead is the culprit.